# An interesting Legendre symbol identity: $\left (\frac{a}{p} \right ) = \prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}}^{}\frac{\sin(2\pi ah/p)}{\sin(2\pi h/p)}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, quadratic-residues

If we call $\mathscr{H}$ a one-half set of reduced residues (mod $p$), $p$ is  a prime,  if $\mathscr{H}$ has the property that:

$h \in \mathscr{H}$ if and only if $-h \notin \mathscr{H}$

Let $\mathscr{H}$ and $\mathscr{K}$ be two complementary one-half sets. They form the reduced residue system modulo $p$.

There are some propositions about $\mathscr{H}$ and $\mathscr{K}$:

1. if $(a, p) = 1$. Let $\nu$ be the number of $h \in \mathscr{H}$ for which $ah \notin \mathscr{H}$. That is $h \in \mathscr{H}$ but $ah \in \mathscr{K}$.

   Then we can get:
   \begin{split}
      (-1)^{\nu} = \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)
     \end{split}
   $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol
2. $(a, p) = 1$, $a \mathscr{H}$ and $a\mathscr{K}$ are complementary one-half sets.

   That is $a \mathscr{H}$ and $a\mathscr{K}$ are disjoint and form the reduced residue system modulo $p$.

I wonder how to get the following equation:

\begin{split}
\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)  = \prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}}^{}\frac{\sin(2\pi ah/p)}{\sin(2\pi h/p)} 
\end{split}
for any integer $a$ and odd prime $p$.

Here are the hints:

Notice that $a\mathscr{H} = (a\mathscr{H} \cap \mathscr{H}) \cup(a\mathscr{H} \cap \mathscr{K})$.

Consider the product of elements in  $\mathscr{H}$ and $(\mathscr{H} \cap a\mathscr{H}) \cup(\mathscr{H} \cap a\mathscr{K})$ respectively, and they are equal.

Comment: Have you proved this expression does not depend on the choice of $\mathscr H$?

Comment: @KentaS Of course and thanks for your comment. Actually we can find a periodic function with T = p (which is sin(2π/p) makes that "≡" holds , then we get  "=" holds, that is "≡" can be converted to "=" , so we can get the answer

Comment: So you know that $\sin(2\pi k/p)$ is periodic. What other property is needed for the product equation to be true?

Comment: @Somos I guess no? Maybe I should write it more clearly. $a\equiv b$ (mod p) $\Leftrightarrow $ $sin(\frac{2\pi a}{p})= sin(\frac{2\pi }{p}) $ if p is a prime

Comment: Good catch! It has to be a one-to-one function. But there is one more simple property it must have.

Comment: @Somos But the property is not such clear for me, so it is a little bit confused :D

Comment: I think you forgot that $p$ must be an *odd* prime here. Please include this vital fact in your question.

Comment: @Gangmen Albeit a few months late, I have answered your question. I would appreciate it if you looked over my answer to see if it is/was what you were looking for. : ) $\tag*{}$ I'm somewhat surprised that you're the first one to ask about this sort of Legendre symbol identity on MSE (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: @C-RAM Thanks for your comment and I wonder where is the identity mentioned before MSE?

Comment: @Gangmen This is a slight generalization of an identity of Eisenstein (I think) which is the special case where $\mathscr{H}=\{1,2,...,(p-1)/2\}$, which he uses to prove quadratic reciprocity. I'm surprised no-one has asked about it because that special case appears on the Wikipedia page for [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Legendre_symbol_and_quadratic_reciprocity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be an integer and $p$ be an odd prime. Define
$$L=\prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi ah/p)}{\sin(2\pi h/p)}$$
We seek to prove that $L=\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$.

We first prove (*lemma*) that for all $k\geq 0$,

$$L=\prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}h/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^kh/p)}$$

Suppose that the above formula is true for some specific $k\geq 0$, then we may write

$$
L=\prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}h/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^kh/p)}\prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{K}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}h/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^kh/p)}
$$

Noticing that $h\in\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{K}$ iff $-h\in\mathscr{K}\cap a\mathscr{H}$, we have that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
L&=\prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}h/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^kh/p)}\prod_{h\in\mathscr{K}\cap a\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}(-h)/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^k(-h)/p)}\\
&=\prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}h/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^kh/p)}\prod_{h\in\mathscr{K}\cap a\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}h/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^kh/p)}\\
&=\prod_{h\in a\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}h/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^kh/p)}\\
&=\prod_{h\in \mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+2}h/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}h/p)}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since the base case of $k=0$ is true by definition, by induction, we may conclude the lemma.

From the above lemma, we see that if $n=o(a)$ is the order of $a$ (so $a^n=1$), we obtain the telescoping product
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
L^n&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^{k+1}h/p)}{\sin(2\pi a^kh/p)}\\
&=\prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi a^nh/p)}{\sin(2\pi h/p)}\\
&=1\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and thus $L\in\{-1,1\}$. Now, let $\mathscr{M}=\{1,2,\cdots,(p-1)/2\}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Note that $|\mathscr{M}\cap\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{K}|=|(-\mathscr{M})\cap\mathscr{K}\cap a\mathscr{H}|$, and note that if $x\ne 0\pmod p$,
$$
\text{sgn}[\sin(2\pi x/p)]=
\begin{cases}
-1  & \text{if }x\in -\mathscr{M} \\
1  & \text{if }x\in \mathscr{M} \\
\end{cases}
$$
From those two facts, we have that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{sgn}(L)&=\prod_{h\in \mathscr{H}}\text{sgn}[\sin(2\pi h/p)]\text{sgn}[\sin(2\pi ah/p)]\\
&=(-1)^{|(-\mathscr{M})\cap\mathscr{H}|+|(-\mathscr{M})\cap a\mathscr{H}|}\\
&=(-1)^{2|(-\mathscr{M})\cap\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{H}|+|(-\mathscr{M})\cap\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{K}|+|(-\mathscr{M})\cap\mathscr{K}\cap a\mathscr{H}|}\\
&=(-1)^{|(-\mathscr{M})\cap\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{K}|+|(-\mathscr{M})\cap\mathscr{K}\cap a\mathscr{H}|}\\
&=(-1)^{|(-\mathscr{M})\cap\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{K}|+|\mathscr{M}\cap\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{K}|}\\
&=(-1)^{|\mathscr{H}\cap a\mathscr{K}|}\\
&=(-1)^{\nu}\\
&=\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)
\end{split}    
\end{equation}
Finally, since $\text{sgn}(L)=\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ and $L\in\{-1,1\}$, then
$$\boxed{L=\prod_{h\in\mathscr{H}}\frac{\sin(2\pi ah/p)}{\sin(2\pi h/p)}=\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)}$$
as desired.